# Hide Shared Network Drive in Finder

Tags: network, finder, backup, sharing, nas

Is there any way to hide a shared network drive in Finder? I don't want to hide all shared drives, just one. I am using an NAS server for backup purposes and I don't want users to be able see or eject the drive in Finder. I know how to hide mounted network shares with chflags, but I want to hide the drive too.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found so far is to map the share manually to /Volumes/.hiddensharename.

Comment: Is this still the case?  I'm having a similar issue.